# SHA 1 Hash key is same for all application?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, sha1, google-authentication

I have integrated Google login in my Android application before one month. Now I am planning to launch another application with different package name. I am trying to implement Google login in this application too.

When I have generated and pasted SHA 1 to google and its giving error like below

```
Duplicate fingerprint
The fingerprint you specified is already used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project
```

I want know that SHA 1 is same for all project in same machine even We change package name in application ?

What is solution for use Google login in another application ? I am confused because Google ask package name with Google Auth. I have marked that in new package also Google signin working fine but it will cause issue in future ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every app has a different SHA key fingerprint. You need to update it for every project that you make.

For Example: If I am updating my app and I create a new project, ill have to add another SHA key to the firebase project under the settings of the app in firebase.[image]